# Using only part of comma delimited files

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I know that in Python, if you have a comma-delimited file that reads something like

```
1,5
2,4
3,3
4,2
5,1
```

you can do something similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt('example.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, label='myLine')
```

and that will plot an X,Y line of the data; however, I'm curious - I have a CDF that is setup with 3 columns  like

```
1/1/2016, 5, 0
1/2/2016, 4, 1
1/3/2016, 3, 2
1/4/2016, 2, 3
1/5/2016, 1, 4
1/6/2016, 0, 5
```

and I want to plot the date as the X with the second column as "Y1" and the third column as Y2" so that you will have two lines on the same graph. I'm still new to Python, and I know how you can statically graph multiple lines along one another, but my question is if there was a way to take this single file and just take parts of the data at a time, rather than Python expecting the entire series of each row and wanting to construct a X,Y,Z graph instead.

Comment: Take a look at the `usecols` option to `numpy.loadtxt`. Doesn't that do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) with `usecols=(1, 2)`:

> usecols : sequence, optional - Which columns to read, with 0 being the first. For example, usecols = (1,4,5) will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns. The default, None, results in all columns being read.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone down-voted your response, but it's in the right direction of what I need. Barmar linked my question to one very similar to mine with a coded example of how to use it. Thanks Ami!